# How to make accordion expand on hover instead of on click using materializecss framework

Tags: javascript, accordion, materialize

How to make accordion expand on hover instead of on click using materializecss framework (http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) ?

Using this code accordion expands on click only, but not on hover.

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
 <li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could use javascript to trigger a click on hover.

Comment: I tried it using: $( "#hoverOnIt" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).trigger('click');
}); but it didn't work. You have any idea how can I use it? (By the way I'm using MeteorJS)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery's `mouseover` (since materialize already uses jQuery) to trigger click **does** work, check this

```js
$( ".collapsible div" ).mouseover(function() { $(this).trigger('click'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```